# How do I find out if a SQLite index is unique? (With SQL)

Tags: sqlite

I want to find out, with an SQL query, whether an index is UNIQUE or not. I'm using SQLite 3.

I have tried two approaches:

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'sqlite_autoindex_user_1'
```

This returns information about the index ("type", "name", "tbl_name", "rootpage" and "sql"). Note that the sql column is empty when the index is automatically created by SQLite.

```
PRAGMA index_info(sqlite_autoindex_user_1);
```

This returns the columns in the index ("seqno", "cid" and "name").

Any other suggestions?

**Edit:** The above example is for an auto-generated index, but my question is about indexes in general. For example, I can create an index with "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index1 ON visit (user, date)". It seems no SQL command will show if my new index is UNIQUE or not.

Comment: Can you give on example where an automatically generated index is not unique?  The ones I've seen have always been unique.

Comment: autoindex is generated for the primary key, which is by definition unique

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
PRAGMA INDEX_LIST('table_name');
```

Returns a table with 3 columns:

1. `seq` Unique numeric ID of index
2. `name` Name of the index
3. `unique` Uniqueness flag (nonzero if `UNIQUE` index.)

**Edit**

Since SQLite 3.16.0 you can also use table-valued pragma functions which have the advantage that you can `JOIN` them to search for a specific table and column. See [@mike-scotty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53629321/12048).

Answer (score 5):

Since noone's come up with a good answer, I think the best solution is this:

- If the index starts with "sqlite_autoindex", it is an auto-generated index for a single UNIQUE column
- Otherwise, look for the UNIQUE keyword in the sql column in the table sqlite_master, with something like this:

  SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'index' AND sql LIKE '%UNIQUE%'

Comment: that first point is not quite right. If the index starts with "sqlite_autoindex", it is an auto-generated index for the Primary Key. But if the PK is multiple columns, then "single UNIQUE column" is not true. I have one infront of me here that is a composite PK i.e. two columns that together are unique (but alone are not).

Answer (score 3):

As of sqlite 3.16.0 you could also use pragma functions:

```
SELECT distinct il.name
  FROM sqlite_master AS m,
       pragma_index_list(m.name) AS il,
       pragma_index_info(il.name) AS ii
 WHERE m.type='table' AND il.[unique] = 1;
```

The above statement will list all names of unique indexes.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.name as table_name, ii.name as column_name
  FROM sqlite_master AS m,
       pragma_index_list(m.name) AS il,
       pragma_index_info(il.name) AS ii
 WHERE m.type='table' AND il.[unique] = 1;
```

The above statement will return all tables and their columns if the column is part of a unique index.

From the [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html):

> The table-valued functions for PRAGMA feature was added in SQLite version 3.16.0 (2017-01-02). Prior versions of SQLite cannot use this feature.

Answer (score 2):

you can programmatically build a select statement to see if any tuples point to more than one row. If you get back three columns, foo, bar and baz, create the following query

```
select count(*) from t
group by foo, bar, baz
having count(*) > 1
```

If that returns any rows, your index is not unique, since more than one row maps to the given tuple. If sqlite3 supports derived tables (I've yet to have the need, so I don't know off-hand), you can make this even more succinct:

```
select count(*) from (
    select count(*) from t
    group by foo, bar, baz
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

This will return a single row result set, denoting the number of duplicate tuple sets. If positive, your index is not unique.

Comment: Of course, this still won't tell you if the index allows duplicates but there don't happen to be any yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are close:

1) If the index starts with `"sqlite_autoindex"`, it is an auto-generated index for the primary key .  However, this will be in the `sqlite_master` or `sqlite_temp_master` tables depending depending on whether the table being indexed is temporary.

2) You need to watch out for table names and columns that contain the substring `unique`, so you want to use:

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'index' AND sql LIKE 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX%'
```

See the sqlite website documentation on [Create Index](http://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)